# How to change order of custom module theme output?

Tags: theming

I need to add some top links and sub top links . I altered hook_theme function and created two templates for these 
code is like this-

```
function acts_theme() {
    return array(
            'acts_top_links' => array(
                    'variables' => array(
                            'links' => NULL,
                            'activelink' => NULL,
                        ),
                    'template' => 'acts-topmenu',
            ),
            'acts_submenu_links' => array(
                    'variables' => array(
                            'links' => NULL,
                            'activelink' => NULL,
                        ),
                    'template' => 'acts-submenu',
            ),
    );
}
function template_preprocess_acts_top_links(&$variables){
    $toplinks=$variables['links'];
    $activelink=$variables['activelink'];
    $variables['toplinks']=$toplinks;
    $variables['activelink']=$activelink;

}
function template_preprocess_acts_submenu_links(&$variables){
    $toplinks=$variables['links'];
    $activelink=$variables['activelink'];
    $variables['sublinks']=$toplinks;
    $variables['activelink']=$activelink;
}
```

Now I am using these theme output as-

```
function acts_display(){
    $build['acts_toplinks'] = array(
            '#theme' => 'acts_top_links',
            '#links' => $toplinks,
            '#activelink'=>'Company Law',
    );
    $build['acts_sublinks'] = array(
            '#theme' => 'acts_submenu_links',
            '#links' => $submenulinks,
            '#activelink'=>'/companylaw/acts',
    );

    $build['acts_table_rows'] = array(
            '#theme' => 'table',
            '#rows' => $rows,
            '#empty' => t('Currently there are no active content'),
    );
return $build;
}
```

I expect output as -
first to show- top links, then sub menu links and then table but output exactly reverse- 
first I get table,then sub menu links and then top links
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try just adding `#weight` to the arrays in `$build()`?

Comment: Yes, this worked with #weight, Post it as answer, will mark as an correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the `#weight` property to the arrays in $build() then that will allow you to order them e.g.:

```php
$build['acts_table_rows'] = array(
        '#theme' => 'table',
        '#rows' => $rows,
        '#empty' => t('Currently there are no active content'),
        '#weight' => 99,
);
```